# What is the result of while(i=20) or any number in general in a C program?

Tags: c

Came across this question somewhere-

**What is the output of the following program**

```
int main(void) {
    int  i = 10 ; 
    while ( i = 20 )  
    printf ( "\nA computer buff!" ) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I know that every non-zero number is treated as true in C but I haven't been able to figure out the result of using an assignment operator inside while. When I run the code "A computer buff" got printed unknown number of times in a loop. I know it's a stupid question but question nonetheless.

Comment: `main()` --> `int main(void)`.

Comment: `When I run the code "A computer buff" got printed 20 times in a loop` - Are you sure it only printed 20 times?

Comment: If it only printed 20 lines, then the code you posted is missing a decrement somewhere.

Comment: BTW, who started the disease of printing newlines **at the beginning** of a string?

Comment: I have no idea. This is the code that was written. I didn't really bother to remove the new line escape sequence from there.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings! Any halfway recent compiler will warn about such crap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should be an infinite loop, because `i = 20` will yield 20 as a result of the assignment expression.

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/474dd6e2.aspx)

> An assignment operation assigns the value of the right-hand operand to
>   the storage location named by the left-hand operand. Therefore, the
>   left-hand operand of an assignment operation must be a modifiable
>   l-value. After the assignment, an assignment expression has the value
>   of the left operand but is not an l-value.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I wanted to know. I know it was treating it as an infinite loop just couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 4):

In your code

```
 while ( i = 20 )
```

is essentially assigning 20 to `i` and then taking the `i` as the conditional check for `while` loop. As there in no `break`ing condition inside the loop body, it is effectively an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily check it on *nix by using the -S option in gcc.
I took this file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main( ){  
   int  i = 10 ; 
   while ( i == 20 )  
   printf ( "\nA computer buff!" );
}
```

with `gcc -S test.c` and it gave me out this assambly:

```
    .file   "c.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "\nA computer buff!"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $10, -4(%rbp)
    nop
.L2:
    movl    $20, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    jmp .L2
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

You can see at `jmp .L2` that this is the only branch, responsible for the loop, which is uncondicional. `movl  $20, -4(%rbp)` is the assignment of 20 to i.

Comment: Interesting, but assembly does not tell you more than the C code.

Comment: Assembly does tell us exactly what will happen, so when you're not sure of what C will do in a case, it helps.

What we can see here is that it will enter in the loop, and then, because there is no loop-enter condition and the only jump is `jmp .L2`, this code will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Exactly, seeing the assambly code dosnt require us to know what C standart defines, but we can directly see what the code does. In that way it shows us everything, that C promises to realize executed.

Answer (score 0):

while(1) is infinite loop so its execute number of time. If you want to move out from the loop after the first iteration then use break statement in loop.